# jframe always on top of another one

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtree, jinternalframe

i am a beginner in java and i am trying to make jFrame Always on top of another and sticked to the first one if it minimized the second jframe also minimize just in that project not all over my computer

or any body tell me how to use jInternalFrame to do that

Comment: and what have you tried so far? Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i am tried to follow an example of code to add jTree to the frame by code but not by swing and every time i do that all the swing component on the jframe do not show untill i remove the jtree that i added to the jframe by code so i want to add jtree on an jframe separate of the main jframe and sticked to the main one as a solution of that problem but i can not make the second jframe stick above that main one

Comment: any body will help ?

Comment: For anyone else stumbling upon this question, your application should have one and only one `JFrame`.  You use modal `JDialogs` to display information that doesn't fit well on the main GUI.